# Unclear pointer defect in program

Tags: c++, gcc, openssl, des

Im trying to build modified example of usage of DES CBC EDE on openssl. Im using gcc version 4.4.6 (Buildroot 2012.02) compiling for arm (not my choise of compiler) on ubuntu 10.04. Here is a problem: when pointer declaration is uncommented - everything is normal. Test message deciphers. But when pointer declaration gets commented - test message shows only 2 first letters after deciphering. I just can not understand what could do a declaration of an unused pointer. Here is code:

```
#include <openssl/des.h>
#include <cstring>

#define BUFSIZE 512

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {


    unsigned char in[BUFSIZE] = {};
    unsigned char out[BUFSIZE] = {};
    unsigned char back[BUFSIZE] = {};
    unsigned char *strangePointer = &out[0];  // what is wrong with it?
    int len;

    DES_cblock key1, key2, key3;
    DES_cblock ivsetup = {0xE1, 0xE2, 0xE3, 0xD4, 0xD5, 0xC6, 0xC7, 0xA8};
    DES_cblock ivecLocal;
    DES_key_schedule ks1, ks2, ks3;

    const char* key = "0A0A0B0B0C0C0A0A0B0B0C0C";

    memcpy(&key1,key,8);
    memcpy(&key2,key + 8,8);
    memcpy(&key2,key + 16,8);

    DES_set_odd_parity(&key1);
    DES_set_odd_parity(&key2);
    DES_set_odd_parity(&key3);

    DES_set_key((C_Block *)key1, &ks1);
    DES_set_key((C_Block *)key2, &ks2);
    DES_set_key((C_Block *)key3, &ks3);

    const char* message = "Now is the time for all men to stand up and be counted";
    /* 64 bytes of plaintext */
    len = strlen(message);
    memcpy(in,message,len);

    printf("Plaintext: [%s]\n", in);

    memcpy(ivecLocal, ivsetup, sizeof(ivsetup));
    DES_ede3_cbc_encrypt(in, out, len, &ks1, &ks2, &ks3, &ivecLocal, DES_ENCRYPT);

    int lenout = 0;
    while(out[lenout] != '\0') ++lenout;

    memcpy(ivecLocal, ivsetup, sizeof(ivsetup));
    DES_ede3_cbc_encrypt(out, back, lenout, &ks1, &ks2, &ks3, &ivecLocal, DES_DECRYPT);

    printf("Decrypted Text: [%s]\n", back);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why is this tagged [tag:c] and [tag:c++]? Which is it? (it includes `<cstring>` so must be C++ ... but then you don't qualify `std::memcpy` so it's not portable C++ either)

Comment: @Jonathan Wakely it is C++

Comment: It certainly doesn't look like C++. C-style casts, C-style IO, C-style arrays. The only C++ thing about it are the includes and `using namespace std;`. C/C++ is not a programming language and the gap between C and C++ has widened since C++ was first formulated.

Comment: Oh I missed the `using namespace std`. Well if it's C++ it shouldn't be tagged [c]! Don't use both tags unless your question really about **both** languages, e.g. comparing the two or asking about differences between the two. Don't use both tags for "C/C++" questions, because as Tibor says that's not a language.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have several things incorrect in your code. I'll start with the simple answer first:

Your third key isn't even populated with key data. It is random data on the local activation stack.

```
memcpy(&key1,key,8);
memcpy(&key2,key + 8,8);
memcpy(&key2,key + 16,8); // <<=== NOTE still key2
```

Oh, copy-paste, ye are a cruel and heartless wench. Anyway, by *removing* the variable you're commenting out, this key is moving further up (or down, depending on your implementation) the stack in memory, and the result is a different value . But the bottom line, you're using indeterminate data for your third key.

But that isn't the entire problem. That change in key exposes *another* issue, you're output length calculation, which is also flat-wrong. This:

```
int lenout = 0;
while(out[lenout] != '\0') ++lenout;
```

assumes the length of the output cipher can be found by searching for a `0`-byte. The DES algorithm can easily emit such a byte *anywhere* in an encryption block.  This is plain wrong. The size of the output of a `DES_ede3_cbc_encrypt` encryption operation is always a multiple of the block size, which for DES is 8 bytes (not coincidentally the size of a `DES_cblock`), The correct calculation of your output buffer size is:

```
int lenout = ((len + sizeof(DES_cblock) - 1)/sizeof(DES_cblock))*sizeof(DES_cblock);
```

which may seem like a helluva lot, but in the end all this does is round up to the nearest multiple of the block length. Further, you don't even *need* the `input` buffer. The API will do the calculation for you if you simply pass your input data message and its true length. But I leave that for you to finish (hint: just remove `input` and pass `message`).

the result is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <openssl/des.h>

#define BUFSIZE 512

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    unsigned char in[BUFSIZE] = {};
    unsigned char out[BUFSIZE] = {};
    unsigned char back[BUFSIZE] = {};
    int len;

    DES_cblock key1, key2, key3;
    DES_cblock ivsetup = {0xE1, 0xE2, 0xE3, 0xD4, 0xD5, 0xC6, 0xC7, 0xA8};
    DES_cblock ivecLocal;
    DES_key_schedule ks1, ks2, ks3;

    const char* key = "0A0A0B0B0C0C0A0A0B0B0C0C";

    memcpy(&key1,key,8);
    memcpy(&key2,key + 8,8);
    memcpy(&key3,key + 16,8);

    DES_set_odd_parity(&key1);
    DES_set_odd_parity(&key2);
    DES_set_odd_parity(&key3);

    DES_set_key(&key1, &ks1);
    DES_set_key(&key2, &ks2);
    DES_set_key(&key3, &ks3);

    const char* message = "Now is the time for all men to stand up and be counted";
    len = strlen(message);
    memcpy(in,message,len);

    printf("Plaintext: [%s]\n", in);

    memcpy(ivecLocal, ivsetup, sizeof(ivsetup));
    DES_ede3_cbc_encrypt(in, out, len, &ks1, &ks2, &ks3, &ivecLocal, DES_ENCRYPT);

    int lenout = ((len + sizeof(DES_cblock) - 1)/sizeof(DES_cblock))*sizeof(DES_cblock);

    memcpy(ivecLocal, ivsetup, sizeof(ivsetup));
    DES_ede3_cbc_encrypt(out, back, lenout, &ks1, &ks2, &ks3, &ivecLocal, DES_DECRYPT);

    printf("Decrypted Text: [%s]\n", back);

    return 0;
}
```

**Output**

```
Plaintext: [Now is the time for all men to stand up and be counted]
Decrypted Text: [Now is the time for all men to stand up and be counted]
```

Comment: Length formula is not clear. If we replace 'len + sizeof(DES_cblock) - 1' with 'n' and 'sizeof(DES_cblock)' with 'a' it will be len = ((n)/a)*a. isn`t that just n?
Next 'len + sizeof(DES_cblock) - 1' - you just increase length with 7, as I understand, you are not converting it to multiple of 8, doesn`t matter was it multiple of 8 before or not.

Comment: @user3177112 Note the `-1` Specifically `m = ((n+a-1)/a)*a` Suppose `n` is 1, and `a` is 8, then we have `((1+8-1)/8)*8 = 8`. Now suppose `n` is 7. then we have `((7+8-1)/8)*8 = 8`. Finally, suppose `n` is 10, then we have `((10+8-1)/8)*8 = (17/8)*8 = 2*8 = 16`. In other words, The result is `n` rounded *up* to the nearest multiple of `8`.

Comment: @user3177112 in short, if you want to encode 1 to 8 bytes, you're output will always be 8 bytes. To encode 9 to 16 bytes, the output will always be 16 bytes, For 17 to 24 bytes, the output will always be 24 bytes. Etc. To encode 7359 bytes, the output will be `((7359 + 7)/8)*8`, or 7360 bytes after the math. The result is always a multiple of 8 (the block size).

Comment: About the formula - I just forgot about implicit int rounding and treated it like a usual math.

Comment: @user3177112 Well pfft, yeah, that would explain it. No worries. Glad you got it. Best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

You are most probably experiencing a buffer overflow. The declaration of `len` comes after `back` on the stack. If `back` overflows, then `len` will be overwritten. Adding another variable (`strangePointer`) in between adds a gap on the stack that stops len getting overwritten.

Probably increasing `BUFSIZE` should solve your issue.

Comment: No, increasing size up to 1024 doesn`t work. Also I have reassigned value to 'len' after buffer was filled - still doesn`t work. And after first encrypt function call 'len' is not used anymore. 
So is there any way to know needed buffer size and data length in buffer? I use detecting by null terminator, but it seems to me, there can be null bytes in ciphered stream, aren`t they?

Comment: @user3177112 in answer to your last question, *yes*, there can be. Block ciphers operate on (wait for it... *blocks*). At bare minimum the output size will be a multiple of the cipher block size, if that isn't already obvious by my posted answer.

Comment: Im sorry but 'multiple of block size' contains almost zero information about actual size. It could be 8 bytes - could it? 8 is multiple of 8. Or it could be 1024 or 8000000 because they are multiples of block size - 8.

Comment: @user3177112 Do you understand how a block cipher *works* ? I never said the multiple of the block size contains information about the actual *input* size. I said the output size will always be a multiple of the *block size*. **Which**  multiple of the block size is dependent on the input size *rounded **up***. If you want to *retain* the original input size in the output encoding, [see padding algorithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padding_(cryptography)), particularly PKCS5, the most commonly used.